# Как определить какой javascript используется в элементе?

Tags: javascript

При наведении на ссылку появляется анимация. Как найти фрагмент javascript, который отвечает именно за эту анимацию?

Comment: может, это css-анимация?

Comment: @humster_spb это точно javascript. Не могу найти фрагмент в коде

Comment: Почему точно javascript? И где, собственно код? Если хотите изучить javascript, то вы не с того начали.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вы собираетесь изучать код, состоящий из 12 000 строчек? Если да - могу сбросить.

Comment: Ищите по классу\ид\элементу и будет вам счастье

Comment: Я собирался ответить на ваш вопрос. Вижу, что уже не нужно)